# I am facing issue in EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Recently when I was working in blender suddenly their is noise or pixelation around edges when I add light source in render mode in EEVEE engine.

Everything is fine in cycles. I have already tried viewport denoising and sample increase but nothing works.

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: This has already been asked https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293381/blender-3-5-torus-in-render-preview-with-evee-showing-glittering-artifact

Comment: As Duarte said, this graphics issue has appeared before. However, it is rare, and not related to the file or to Blender itself. The color and placement of the squares also suggests a hardware problem. Sadly, as far as I know, we cannot help you here.